# How do I Show ALL posts for Catagories and Tags?

Tags: posts

How can I get Wordpress to ignore "Blog pages show at most" when a user clicks on a "Catagory" or "Tag" link ?

THANKS

Answer (score 1):

Try this (add to your theme's functions.php):

```
function my_unlimited_posts_list( $vars ) {
  if ( isset($vars['category_name']) || isset($vars['tag']) )
    $vars['posts_per_page'] = -1;

  return $vars;
}
add_filter( 'request', 'my_unlimited_posts_list' );
```

Answer (score 1):

in your category.php or archive.php (depends on your theme)
add this before the loop:

```
if (is_category() || is_tag()){
    global $query_string;
    query_posts( $query_string . "&posts_per_page=-1" );
}
```